# Code is getting slower with every run (PowerPoint VSTO)

Tags: performance, vsto, powerpoint

I'm writting a PowerPoint AddIn (VSTO) which makes the following (very roughly):
 1. Loop through all slides
 2. Loop through all tags for each slide and write the tag information to a List-Object
3. Do some calucations on the List-Object and update some columns in the list-Object
4. Loop through the List-Object and write the tags back to the sorresponding slides / tags

I recognized that this code runs for every run slower and slowwer - the 10th run is 3-4 times slower than the first one.
I also see the memory usage goes up for every run.

What are my tools to check where the bottle neck is?
How can I find the problem which makes my code slower for every run?
Is there a way to clear the memory etc. the AddOn uses after each run?

I'm sorry to ask such general question, but please let me know if you need more details

My PowerPoint has 32 Slides - for each slide i want to write tags (in this example 49 Tags). Because of updates etc. the code is executed several times by the user. I simulate this by doing it 11 times automatically. I recognize here the same behavior as by user interaction: the writing of the tags for the 32 Slides is getting slower with every execute.

I reduced my code to the minimum which has the same behavior. I tried also to first delete the tags on every slide but without success.

```
        private void btn_DoIt10Times_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        SlideTags_Write();

        watch.Stop();
        //MessageBox.Show("Time spend: " + watch.Elapsed);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            SlideTags_Write();
        }

        Stopwatch watch2 = new Stopwatch();
        watch2.Start();

        SlideTags_Write();

        watch2.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Time 1st run: " + watch.Elapsed + "\n Time 11th run: " + watch2.Elapsed);
    }

    public void SlideTags_Write()
    {
        PowerPoint.Presentation oPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;

        foreach (PowerPoint.Slide oSlide in oPresentation.Slides)
        {
            //for (int iTag = 1; iTag <= oSlide.Tags.Count; iTag++)
            //{
            //    oSlide.Tags.Delete(oSlide.Tags.Name(iTag));
            //}

            for (int iTag = 1; iTag < 50; iTag++)
            {
                oSlide.Tags.Add("Tag_" + iTag.ToString(), "Tag Value " + iTag.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should share a bit of your code. When and how often do you start the loop through the slides? Do you release the objects after using? Do you extend your `list` object everytime so it will get bigger and bigger?

Comment: We need to see your code to answer your question.

Comment: I've added the code - any idea?